# Check the url in a Geb/Spock test

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

In my Spock functional test, I want to test that the current location of the browser is not a certain url.  I know I can do:

```
try {
    at(PageWithUrlIDontWant)
    // do something
} catch (AssertionError) {
    // pass because this is the common branch
}
```

However, this is using exceptions to control branching.  Is there a way, besides `at`, to check what url the browser is at?  I have tried `page.pageUrl` and `browser.pageUrl` but they are both null.

Comment: Using isat seems to be giving me a WaitTimeoutException whwen it is not at the page...

Comment: Update to comment: I believe the WaitTimeoutException is happening because my at-checker checks for an element that is not found on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Geb 0.7.0, there is a new `isAt()` method on the class `Browser`. `GebSpec` proxies methodMissing calls to it's `Browser` instance so this method is available in your test. This method returns true/false instead of throwing an exception and should be exposed.

Example:

```
def "navigating to GoodPage doesn't up at BadPage"() {
    when:
    to GoodPage

    then:
    !isAt(BadPage)
}
```